# How to make a copy to previous value to another column

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a Postgres database which is have a tons of data and including schema and all database attributes. I want to create open price which is pulling from to same symbol previous close price.

My data is like:

```
ID  DATE        SYMBOL      OPEN    CLOSE
1   1.01.2020   ABC                  2,33
2   1.01.2020   XYZ                 10,32
3   1.01.2020   KLM                 30,33
4   1.01.2020   DEF                 50,78
5   3.01.2020   ABC                  3,00
6   3.01.2020   KLM                 31,00
7   4.01.2020   ABC                  4,00
8   4.01.2020   XYZ                 13,00
9   4.01.2020   KLM                 25,00
10  4.01.2020   DEF                 48,00
11  5.01.2020   XYZ                 11,50
12  5.01.2020   DEF                 47,53
13  7.01.2020   ABC                  4,58
14  7.01.2020   XYZ                 12,54
15  7.01.2020   KLM                 25,78
16  7.01.2020   DEF                 48,33
```

I created Open colum which is should be have previous symbol prices.

My expect output:

```
ID  DATE        SYMBOL      OPEN    CLOSE
1   01.01.2020  ABC                  2,33
2   01.01.2020  XYZ                 10,32
3   01.01.2020  KLM                 30,33
4   01.01.2020  DEF                 50,78
5   03.01.2020  ABC          2,33    3,00
6   03.01.2020  KLM         30,33   31,00
7   04.01.2020  ABC          3,00    4,00
8   04.01.2020  XYZ         10,32   13,00
9   04.01.2020  KLM         31,00   25,00
10  04.01.2020  DEF         50,78   48,00
11  05.01.2020  XYZ         13,00   11,50
12  05.01.2020  DEF         48,00   47,53
13  07.01.2020  ABC          4,00    4,58
14  07.01.2020  XYZ         11,50   12,54
15  07.01.2020  KLM         25,00   25,78
16  07.01.2020  DEF         47,53   48,33
```

Open value = Previous close price value
ABC 01.01.2020 close price 2,33 = ABC 03.01.2020  open price 2,33

My database is active and fetching new data everyday which should be OPEN column must be filled up with (same symbols) previous close price data.

All symbolms doesnt have a price in some day and its getting over 100.000+ column at this moment. I tried something with sql query but didnt figure out. Im kindly new as database query. As I can understand documentation the following [definitions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/dml-update.html)

So Can this be possible? If so, how? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       lag(close) over (partition by symbol order by date) as prev_close
from t;
```

If you want to *update* the value in the table, you can use `join` (after adding the column):

```
update t
    set open = tt.prev_close
    from (select t.*,
                 lag(close) over (partition by symbol order by date) as prev_close
          from t
         ) tt
    where tt.id = t.id and
          tt.prev_close is distinct from t.open;
```